# How to do command substitution in fish shell?

Tags: fish

How would a Bash (or other POSIX shell) command like this have to be expressed in fish?

```
ls -l $(which vim) # or
ls -l `which vim`
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `fish`, `$` is used only for variable expansion.  Omit the `$` from the command and you should be good.  Say:

```
ls -l (which vim)
```

You might also want to refer to the documentation: [Command Substitutions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#command-substitutions)

Comment: and this one: `$(npm bin)/cowsay hello` ?

Comment: @Yukulélé `npm=(npm bin) $npm/cowsay hello`

Comment: Or `eval "$(npm bin)"/cowsay hello`

Answer (score 1):

As of Fish version 3.4.0, command substitution may now be done with *either* `$()` or `()` grouping.  E.g.:

```
ls -l $(which vim) # or
ls -l (which vim)
```

For versions prior to 3.4.0, only the `()` form is available.

Backticks, which do work in Bash and other POSIX shells, are not available as a command substitution operator.  In general, backticks are no longer *recommended* in any shell for this purpose, but some habits (and old documentation) are hard to break.

Comment: Both notations are not supported (fish 3.6.1) when we want to start with it eg. (which vim) --version -->>fish: command substitutions not allowed here

Comment: True, that's not a valid use for command substitution.  The result of a command substitution is essentially the *text* result (perhaps an oversimplification) which is then passed to another command.  In the example above, `which vim` returns the path to `vim` as text that the `ls -l` command can then process.  If want to actually evaluate the text results in the shell itself, you'd need to `eval $(which vim) --version`.  However, that has exactly the same result as `vim --version`, so why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking to override an alias?  If that's the case, then you want `command  vim --version`.  That will make sure to call the *command* (rather than an alias or function).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to use `string split` inside `()`, otherwise `-lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0` will be incorrectly interpreted by the compiler as "go find a library named `gio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0`, with the spaces being part of its name".

To quote the [official tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html)

> Unlike other shells, fish does not split command substitutions on any whitespace (like spaces or tabs), only newlines. This can be an issue with commands like `pkg-config` that print what is meant to be multiple arguments on a single line. To split it on spaces too, use `string split`.
>
> ````
> > printf '%s\n' (pkg-config --libs gio-2.0)
> -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
> > printf '%s\n' (pkg-config --libs gio-2.0 | string split " ")
> -lgio-2.0
> -lgobject-2.0
> -lglib-2.0 ```
> ````